# How To Make Pipeline Continue On Reusable Workflow Error Github Actions

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to make an alert if any reusable workflow of the matrix gets an error on GitHub actions. Alert will be something like

> `'deployment failed'`

But the problem is I am using the reusable workflow as a matrix. If any step of the matrix fails, I don't want the matrix to continue. I know that it's ensured by default `fail-fast:true` parameter. But on error, the whole pipeline stops. I want it continue to have an alert.

```
deploy:
    needs: [ prepare-heml-template ]
    strategy:
        max-parallel: 1
        matrix:
            args: [ 'lint', 'diff', 'sync' ]
    name: 'Helm ${{ matrix.args }}'
    uses: github-actions/pipelines/.github/workflows/run-helmfile.yml@get_result_of_run_helmfile


send-post-deployment-message:
    needs: [ deploy ]
    name: 'Send Post-Deployment Message'
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, docker-runner ]
    steps:
        -   uses: actions/checkout@v3

        -   name: 'Send deployment succeeded message'
            if: success()
            uses: ./.github/actions/write-pr-comment
            with:
                message: |
                    :white_check_mark: [Ad-hoc deployment](${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}/\
                    ${{ github.event.repository.name }}/actions/runs/${process.env.GITHUB_RUN_ID}) is finished successfully

        -   name: 'Send deployment failed message'
            if: failure()
            uses: ./.github/actions/write-pr-comment
            with:
                message: |
                    :x: [Ad-hoc deployment](${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}/\
                    ${{ github.event.repository.name }}/actions/runs/${process.env.GITHUB_RUN_ID}) is failed
```

Note: If I put `continue-on-error:true` inside of the reusable workflow, then the matrix does not stop on error (fail-fast does not work in that case)

Note 2: I don't want to break down the matrix but if there is no other way to solve the problem, I'll do

Answer (score 1):

The solution is putting

```
if: ${{ always() }}
```

to the following jobs after the one with matrix. No need to put continue-on-error to the reusable workflow

```
send-post-deployment-message:
    needs: [ deploy ]
    if: ${{ always() }}
    name: 'Send Post-Deployment Message'
    runs-on: [ self-hosted, docker-runner ]
    steps:
        -   uses: actions/checkout@v3

        -   name: 'Send deployment succeeded alert'
            if: needs.deploy.result == 'success'
            uses: ./.github/actions/write-pr-comment
            with:
                message: |
                    :white_check_mark: [Ad-hoc deployment](${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}/\
                    ${{ github.event.repository.name }}/actions/runs/${process.env.GITHUB_RUN_ID}) is finished successfully

        -   name: 'Send deployment failed alert'
            if: needs.deploy.result == 'failure'
            uses: ./.github/actions/write-pr-comment
            with:
                message: |
                    :x: [Ad-hoc deployment](${{ github.server_url }}/${{ github.event.repository.owner.login }}/\
                    ${{ github.event.repository.name }}/actions/runs/${process.env.GITHUB_RUN_ID}) is failed
```